# Parsing a line in a text file into a table based on selection in list box

Tags: arrays, vb.net, text-files, record

I'm building a simple app in Visual Basic for school. It's a TNR cat record locator.

Goal: Enter cat's name and details, submit data, data writes to text file and saves cat name as entry in a list box. When clicking a cat name in the list box, the cat's other data populates in a table or collection of text boxes.

I'm not sure how to make the last part happen, where I click on a name in the list box and populate the cat's data.

I can't find a way to do this that makes sense, since I'm still pretty new to the language and programming. Here's my code so far:

```
Public Class Form1

    ' Save input data to text file
    Private Sub BtnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\dkennedy2009\Documents\tnr_record.txt", True)
        file.WriteLine(inptName.Text & inptLocation.Text & inptSex.Text & inptAge.Text & inptFeral.Text & inptCoat.Text & inptTrapped.Text & inptTrapDate.Text & inptVetDate.Text & inptFixDate.Text & inptReleaseDate.Text)
        file.Close()
    End Sub

    ' Create an array for accessing specific lines of data from .txt file:
    Sub read_whole_file()
        Dim sFile As String, sWhole As String
        Dim v As Variant
        sFile = "C:\Users\dkennedy2009\Documents\tnr_record.txt"
        Open sFile For Input As #1
    sWhole = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
        Close #1
    v = Split(sWhole, vbNewLine)
    End Sub

    ' Add saved cat to list
    Private Sub BtnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

        lstCats.Items.Add(inptName.Text)

    End Sub

    ' Delete a cat from list
    Private Sub BtnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

        lstCats.Items.Remove(lstCats.SelectedItem)

    End Sub

' Code for displaying selected cat's details

End Class
```

And here's an image of the app:

[image]

Comment: You need some way of separating each item in a line. Provided a comma is not allowed in any of the data, you could use that with no complications. The complications are that if a comma is allowed in the data, then you will need to surround the data item with double-quotes, and if there is a double-quote in the data then it needs to be represented as `""`, i,e, two consecutive double-quotes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton is right that you need a separator but you could use vbTab or "|" for example to avoid any problems with the data.

Comment: Also, using multiple & operations is not a good idea.  Take a look at StringBuilder instead.

Comment: Finally, consider creating a Class called Cat and using instances of that class to add/delete from lstCats.  That will allow you delete routine to work and will make binding to the Cat properties very easy.